# Getting Child Component Prop from the Parent Component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using following React Native module:
https://github.com/shariqahmed1/react-native-animated-tree-view

I like to get clicked item from a TreeView.

Documentation says I should be able to get clicked item by `onClick prop`.
[image]

My attempt was like that:

```
<TreeView
 onPress={() => console.log(props.onClick)} //Cannot get clicked item
 data={data} //Works Okay
/>
```

I'm able to give source data successfully but I can not get the clicked item from tree view.

How can I get the child component value from parent component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `onClick` inplace of `onPress` as per the doc to get clicked item:

```
onClick={props.onClick} // <-- will call parent component's onClick

// OR

onClick={(item) => props.onClick(item)}  // <-- will call parent component's onClick
```

To check console, try below code :

```
onClick={(item) => { console.log(item); }}
```

Comment: This is definitely what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @ilvthsgm, Glad to know, it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Ref/createRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to give it a unique reference (just like ID) and then you have the access to it:

```
 class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  focusTextInput() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    // tell React that we want to associate the <input> ref
    // with the `textInput` that we created in the constructor
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={this.textInput} />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Focus the text input"
          onClick={this.focusTextInput}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the onclick event handler, use `this.onClick()` instead of `props.onClick()` and in this.onClick, you can access child component using this.textInput.**current** to access the child component.

Comment: Thanks for the generic answer. I didn't know the `Refs` and will use it in the future.